# MySQL data display with different prices JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, codeigniter

I have following tables that related to simple Sales Management System

## store_item

```
+---------+-----------+-----------------------+--------------+
| item_id | item_code |       item_name       | retail_price |
+---------+-----------+-----------------------+--------------+
|       1 |  60002332 | Coolant 1L            |          250 |
|       2 |  60002333 | Coolant 4L            |          950 |
|       3 |  60002334 | GEARON X (SAE90)-20L  |         2500 |
|       4 |  60002335 | GEARON X (SAE90)-210L |        30000 |
+---------+-----------+-----------------------+--------------+
```

## store_update_stock

```
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+
| update_stock_id | invoice_no |    date    | order_status |
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+
|               1 | INV001     | 2019-10-01 | purchase     |
|               2 | INV002     | 2019-10-02 | purchase     |
|               3 | INV003     | 2019-10-03 | purchase     |
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

## store_update_stock_details

+

```
-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+---------------+
| update_stock_details_id | update_stock_id | item | qty | unit_price | available_qty |
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+---------------+
|                       1 |               1 |    1 |   2 |        250 |             2 |
|                       2 |               1 |    1 |  10 |        260 |            10 |
|                       3 |               2 |    2 |   4 |        950 |             4 |
|                       4 |               3 |    4 |   5 |      30000 |             5 |
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+---------------+
```

I tried to perform sales using item_name, qty & unit_price

my controller named Issue.php includes following line too

```
$this->data['products'] = $this->Item_Model->getExistProducts();
```

Related functions in the Item_Model as follows

```
public function isExistProduct($q)
    {
        if (!empty($q)) {

            $this->db->select("store_item.*,store_update_stock.*,sum(qty) as qty, store_update_stock_details.unit_price");
            $this->db->from('store_update_stock_details');
            $this->db->join('store_update_stock', 'store_update_stock_details.update_stock_id=store_update_stock.update_stock_id');
            $this->db->join('store_item', 'store_update_stock_details.item=store_item.item_id', 'right');
            $this->db->where("store_item.item_id= $q");
            $this->db->group_by('store_item.item_id, store_update_stock_details.unit_price');
            $q1 = $this->db->get();


            if ($q1->num_rows() > 0) {
                return $q1->result_array();
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

And the view named, addIssue.php includes following JavaScript code and HTML code

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).on("change", "#item", function () {
        //  console.log($('#item').val());
        $("#salesList").show();
        $.ajax({
            'url': '<?=site_url("issue/isExistProduct/?q=")?>' + $('#item').val(),
            'method': 'GET',
            'success': function (data) {

                var jData = JSON.parse(data);
                if (jData.status == true) {
                    //console.log(jData);
                    $('#request_table').append('<tr>' +
                        '<td ><span id="product" >' + jData.data[0].item_name + '</span>' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="item_id[]" name="item_id[]" value="' + jData.data[0].item_id + '">' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td class="text-center">' + jData.data[0].qty + '</td>' +
                        '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-center rquantity" data-qty-bal="' + jData.data[0].qty + '" autofocus required type="number" step="any" id="qty[]" name="qty[]" ></td>' +
                        '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-right" autofocus required type="number" step="any" id="sales_price[]" name="sales_price[]" value="' + jData.data[0].unit_price + '"></td>' +
                        '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-right" autofocus type="number" step="any" id="discount_price[]" name="discount_price[]" ></td>' +
                        '<td class="text-center" ><i class="fa fa-remove remove" style="cursor: pointer"></i></td>' +
                        '</tr>');
                }

            },
            'error': function () {

            }
        });


    });

    $(document).on("click", ".remove", function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });

    var old_row_qty;
    $(document).on("focus", '.rquantity', function () {
        old_row_qty = $(this).val();
    }).on("change", '.rquantity', function () {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        if ($(this).val() > $(this).data('qty-bal')) {
            $(row).addClass('danger');
            $('#add_sale').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $(row).removeClass('danger');
            $('#add_sale').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        var amount = 0, subTotal = 0;
        $('#request_table >tbody').find('tr').each(function () {
            var rate = parseFloat($(this).find('td:eq(2) > .rquantity').val());
//            $(this).find('.ssubtotal').text(formatNumber(rate));
            amount += rate;
//            subTotal += getNumber($(this).find('td:eq(5)').text());
        });
        $('#request_table  >tfoot>tr').find('th:eq(1)').text(amount);
//        $('#payTable  >tfoot>tr').find('th:eq(2)').text(formatNumber(subTotal));
    });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#salesList").hide();
        var oTable = $('#ExData').dataTable({

            "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "ALL"]],
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            'bProcessing': true, 'bServerSide': true,
            'sAjaxSource': '<?= base_url() . "issue/getIssue" ?>',
            'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                aoData.push({
                    "name": "type",
                    "value": "1 "
                });
                $.ajax({'dataType': 'json', 'type': 'POST', 'url': sSource, 'data': aoData, 'success': fnCallback});
            },
            'fnRowCallback': function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {

            },
            "aoColumns": [{'sName': 'invoice_no'}, {'sName': 'sales_date'}, {'sName': 'rep'}, {'sName': 'dealer_code'}, {'sName': 'dealer_name'}, {'mRender':formatMoney}, {'mRender':formatMoney}, {'mRender': pay_status}, null],
            "fnFooterCallback": function (nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {

            }

        });


    });


</script>
<div class="box box-info">
    <div class="box-body" style="display: block">
        <form action="<?= site_url('issue/addIssue') ?>" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group"><label>Sales Date</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                                </span>
                            <input type="text" name="sales_date" id="sales_date" class="form-control datepicker"
                                   style="cursor: pointer"
                                   value="<?= date('Y-m-d') ?>" readonly>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group"><label>Dealer</label>
                        <select name="dealer" id="dealer" class="form-control select2" required>
                            <option value="">Select Dealer</option>
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($dealer)) {
                                foreach ($dealer as $row) {

                                    ?>

                                    <option value="<?= $row->dealer_id ?>"><?= $row->dealer_code . " - " . $row->dealer_name ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }

                            ?>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group"><label>Rep Code</label>
                        <select name="rep" id="rep" class="form-control select2" required>
                            <option value="">Select Rep</option>
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($rep)) {
                                foreach ($rep as $row) {

                                    ?>

                                    <option value="<?= $row->rep_id ?>"><?= $row->rep_name ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }

                            ?>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group"><label>Invoice No</label>
                        <input type="text" name="invoice_no" id="invoice_no" class="form-control"
                               value="<?= $autoInv ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group"><label>Select Item</label>
                        <select name="item" id="item" class="form-control select2" required>
                            <option value="">Select Item</option>
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($products)) {
                                foreach ($products as $row) {

                                    ?>

                                    <option value="<?= $row->item_id ?>"><?= $row->item_name ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }

                            ?>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>


            <!--table-->
            <div id="salesList">
                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="control-group table-group">
                            <label class="table-label">Sale Items *</label>

                            <div class="controls table-controls">
                                <table id="request_table" width="100%"
                                       class="table items table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr style="background-color: #3c8dbc;color: #ffffff;">
                                        <th class="col-md-3">Item Name</th>
                                        <th class="text-center col-md-2">Available Qty</th>
                                        <th class="text-center col-md-2">Issue Qty</th>
                                        <th class="text-center col-md-2">Unit Price</th>
                                        <th class="text-center col-md-2">Discount</th>

                                        </th>
                                        <th class="col-md-1" style="width: 30px !important; text-align: center;">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"
                                               style="opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50);"></i>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody></tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                    <tr id="tfoot" class="tfoot active">
                                        <th colspan="2">Total</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">0</th>
                                        <th class="text-right"></th>
                                        <th class="text-right"></th>
                                        <th class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"
                                                                   style="opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50);"></i>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <button type="submit" id="add_sale" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><i
                                    class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Sale
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </form>

        <!--end of table-->
    </div>
```

[image: Sales View]

All are working fine.

## Issue

The table store_update_stock_details have two records of item_id -> 1 with different unit_price (250, 260).

## Desired Output

I want to show this two unit_prices with item_name & qty as two lines in the list when perform sales and update available quantities. The item and the available_qty is display correctly & unit_prices didn't display in the view.

What is going wrong. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#request_table').append('<tr>' +
  '<td ><span id="product" >' + jData.data[0].item_name + '</span>' +
  '<input type="hidden" id="item_id[]" name="item_id[]" value="' + jData.data[0].item_id 
  + '">' +
  '</td>' +
  '<td class="text-center">' + jData.data[0].qty + '</td>' +
  '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-center rquantity" data-qty-bal="' + jData.data[0].qty + '" autofocus required type="number" step="any" id="qty[]" name="qty[]" ></td>' +
  '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-right" autofocus required type="number" step="any" id="sales_price[]" name="sales_price[]" value="' + jData.data[0].unit_price + '"></td>' +
  '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-right" autofocus type="number" step="any" id="discount_price[]" name="discount_price[]" ></td>' +
  '<td class="text-center" ><i class="fa fa-remove remove" style="cursor: pointer"></i> 
   </td>' +
'</tr>');
```

Because above function only append the first record to the table,so you need to use the foreach statement to append the entire record